# Remote control feature for iOS devices in AirWatch

Tags: airwatch

We use AirWatch as MDM solution. Is there a feature to help troubleshooting for iOS devices, like remote control? Something similar to Help@work in MobileIron.
If AirWatch doesn't support this: is there any other solution for iOS devices?

Answer (score 2):

Whereas remote view using traditional AirPlay requires devices to be running the Bonjour service and cannot be easily retransmitted to different subnets, AirWatch remote view capabilities use the AirWatch Agent instead of Bonjour and can function over different subnets within the same network. If an end user calls with an issue, simply instruct them to start their AirWatch Agent application and then send a remote view request to view their screen.

--> You can only remote view the IOS device when the MDM agent is opened in the foreground. This is an Apple restriction and not an MDM limitation.

Source : https://my.air-watch.com/help/9.1/en/Content/Platform_Guides/iOS/C/Remote_View_Overview.htm

Answer (score 0):

AirWatch has the `Remote View` feature which allows administrators to assist with troubleshooting by viewing an end user's iOS device from an AirPlay-enabled destination.

Supported destination are :

- AirServer for both Mac OS X or Windows
- X-Mirage for both Moc OS X or Windows
- Reflector for Windows

Ports to configure :

- 7000 for video on Mac
- 7100 for video on Windows
- 5000 for audio on Mac and Windows

Requirements :

- iOS 7 and higher devices to run the `Remote View` command
- iOS 7 and higher Supervised devices to run the `Stop Remote View` command
- AirWatch Agent v4.9.3 and higher

In your AirWatch Console, go the `Details View` page of your iOS device, click on `More` (the one next to `Lock` at the top of the page), then click on `Remote View`. You have to configure a destination before. If it's not done already, click on `Add a destination` on the 1st screen.

Complete documentation is available on [my.air-watch.com](http://my.air-watch.com) under the current name "VMware AirWatch iOS Platform Guide". It's located in "Chapter 6: Additional iOS Configuration".

Comment: does this feature comes in basic package (GREEN MANAGEMENT SUITE) ?

Comment: Yes, Mobile Device Management features are included in the Green Management Suite.

Comment: You should go check in AirWatch Console if the feature is available in the Details View of an iOS 7 device.